# Get users without group by DQL

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two models: Users and Groups with many-to-many relationship. So I need select all users, which hasn't group. It must me realize by DQL.

Ok, something more information. I work in symfony 2 with sonata admin bundle. In my list view I want to show users which has no relationship with group. For example: When admin in admin panel create user, he choose group for this user. But when user register from frontend, this user has no any groups. So, I want to see all this users without groups. In sonata admin bundle in Admin classs I can inherit createQuery method, where I can write my own DQL query. As an example:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->andWhere('o.admin = TRUE');
    $query->orderBy('o.loginDate', 'DESC');

    return $query;
}
```

So, in my case I want choose users without groups, something like this:

```
public function createQuery($context = 'list')
{
    $query = parent::createQuery($context);
    $query->addSelect('g');
    $query->leftJoin('o.groupList', 'g');

    // here I need some DQL which chose users without groups

    return $query;
}
```

So, now can anybody help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I use "ON" keyword in DQL or do I need to use Native Query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748664/can-i-use-on-keyword-in-dql-or-do-i-need-to-use-native-query)

Comment: Please describe your problem a little bit more. This is a programming website, for example can you show your code? It must not need to work, but this should make more clear into which problem in specific you run into.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relationship into user, like a groups property being an ArrayCollection, then you could simply get users where count(u.groups) = 0 or something like that?