# Symfony2, Doctrine2, left join (dql) and its result

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

So we have such dql

```
    $oQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('assets')
        ->addSelect('flags')
        ->addSelect('types')
        ->addSelect('groups')
        ->leftJoin('Site\MainBundle\Entity\123\invFlags', 'flags', Join::WITH, 'assets.flag = flags.flagID')
        ->leftJoin('Site\MainBundle\Entity\123\invTypes', 'types', Join::WITH, 'assets.typeID = types.typeID')
        ->leftJoin('Site\MainBundle\Entity\123\invGroups', 'groups', Join::WITH, 'types.groupID = groups.groupID');

    if (!empty($aFilter)) {
        $bFirst = true;

        foreach ($aFilter as $sKey => $sValue) {

            if ($bFirst) {
                $oQuery->where($oQuery->expr()->eq('assets.' . $sKey, $sValue));
                $bFirst = false;
                continue;
            } else {
                if ($sValue === null) {
                    $oQuery->andWhere($oQuery->expr()->isNull('assets.' . $sKey));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $oQuery->getQuery()->getResult();
```

We call it from repository and have result... BUT. In sql query ($oQuery->getQuery()->getSQL()) I see all columns and proper left join I need, but NOT in result. Why it happens? When I return '->getScalarResult()' I receive all needed data but like array and with prefix of tables

```
array(38) {
  ["assets_id"]=>string(4) "4558"
  ["assets_characterID"]=>string(8) "90206263"
  ["assets_parentItemID"]=>NULL
```

Can I anyhow get simple 'combined' object' with all get methods?

ADD:
Forgot to say that there are no relations in entities.

Comment: Then add the relations.  Your join works because you are explicitly setting the join relations.  But that doesn't help Symfony with the mapping.

Comment: My db is really huge. Entities will be a trouble. But I will think in this way. Thnx.